# React: Pass Function with JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to generate components from a JSON file with React-Native, and am wondering what is the best way to pass a function to a component as a `prop`?

Example, `button` requires the prop `onPress`, so is there a way to pass in a function to the object `onPress` as I have done here:

```
{
      component: "Button",
      props: {
            title: "This is the Title",
            onPress: {() => {Alert.alert("Tapped!")}}
      }
}
```

As this generates an unexpected token error, what is a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra curly brackets around the function declaration that are invalid. Remove those, and you should be good:

```
{
      component: "Button",
      props: {
            title: "This is the Title",
            onPress: () => {Alert.alert("Tapped!")}
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that this does allow this function to be called, but the "Alert" component is not available as it was called from the data file. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you imported or required `Alert` in the file where it's being called?

Comment: Yes, but the stack trace shows that the function is being called in the data.json file that currently holds the dummy data. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you change the JSON file to a .js file, and export your config object? Then, perhaps if the import/require of {Alert} is declared in the file where the alert function is defined, it will carry over.

Comment: I will try that. Eventually, I plan to serve the file remotely. In that case would it even be possible to have the file "export" itself as you recommended?

Comment: Um...probably not? But hard to say without knowing how my previous suggestion affected the situation. My previous suggestion was based on my assumption that there is some bundling/compilation step being handled by something like webpack that recognizes the import/require statement and assembles everything in the way that `Alert` will be in scope. In the case of importing the config from a remote server, without `Alert` being a reference to an object in scope at the time of function invocation, I don't see how it could work.